# Laravel mysqldump create empty file, but same command work when execute via xampp shell

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, xampp

running Laravel 5.2 on Xampp 321 Win7 Mysql5.6 PHP 5.6.3 I cant create BD dump file .sql

```
        $filename = "backup-".Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d_H-i-s').".sql  2>&1";

        try{
          $command = "mysqldump --user=" . env('DB_USERNAME') ." --password=" . env('DB_PASSWORD') . " --host=" . env('DB_HOST') . " " . env('DB_DATABASE') . "  > " . storage_path() . "/" . $filename;
          $returnVar = NULL;
          $output  = NULL;
          //exec command allows you to run terminal commands from php 
          exec($command, $output, $returnVar);
          //dd($command);  
          return 1;    
         }catch(Exception $e){
           return $e->errorInfo; //some error
         }
```

When loading script it generates an empty file! But by doing dd ($ command) and copying paste this text, this command works fine in the Xampp shell. Any ideas please?

Comment: Are you using artisan command?

Comment: no, cmd directly (from shell of xampp panel)

Comment: How do you intend to run it from Laravel? If you want it to run from Laravel, follow instructions here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/artisan

Comment: I would like to execute the task with pure php from a Laravel controller, calling a command to the mysql engine directly, I would like to know if it is possible and why write a .sql file empty 0KB

Comment: Yes, you can call artisan commands from controllers. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/artisan#calling-commands-via-code

Comment: I found one of the causes, when specifying the path as D:\ xampp\ htdocs \ ... there was a line break in D:\. Now adding a backslash plus "D:\\ xampp \ htdocs\..." recognizes the mysql statement. But now, in the .sql file typing the error "Mysqldump is not recognized as an internal or external command, Program or executable batch file" Now file created have 1KB

Answer (score 1):

Solved with this code: setting absolute path of mysqldump adn adding double backslash to url var

```
    $filename = "backup-".date("d-m-Y-H-i-s").".sql";
    $mysqlPath = "D:\\xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump";

    try{
        $command = "$mysqlPath --user=" . env('DB_USERNAME') ." --password=" . env('DB_PASSWORD') . " --host=" . env('DB_HOST') . " " . env('DB_DATABASE') . "  > " . storage_path() . "/" . $filename."  2>&1";
        $returnVar = NULL;
        $output  = NULL;
        exec($command, $output, $returnVar);
        return 1;//ok

     }catch(Exception $e){
        return "0 ".$e->errorInfo; //some error
     }
```

Comment: Problem solved by adding SQL dump absolute path. Thanks